# How to call javascript from code behind for Repeater control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

There is a span element that need to load data dynamically from a Repeater control. 
The problem that I encounter is only first span element can display the value. The subsequent will display blank.

I've simplify the code behind as below.

```
    private int incre = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (RepeaterItem ritem in FeaturedRepeater.Items)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl span = ritem.FindControl("countdown") as HtmlGenericControl;
            span.Load += new EventHandler(test);
        }

    }
    protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlGenericControl span = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "timer(" + incre + ")", true);
        incre++;
    }
```

Javascript function in .aspx file example as below:

```
    function timer(increment, timespan) {
       var id = 'ContentPlaceHolder1_FeaturedRepeater_countdown_' + increment;
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = id;   
    }
```

HTML part:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="FeaturedRepeater"       OnItemDataBound="FeaturedRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span id='countdown' runat="server"></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), string.Format("CallMyFunction{0}", incre), "timer(" + incre + ");", true);
```

you can't register the same key more then one time.
that's why changing `"CallMyFunction"` to  `string.Format("CallMyFunction{0}", incre)` will work

### btw

and `;` after every javascript function call.